# Can we convert horizontal tab items to dropdown menu, If we make zoomin and out of view in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, css, gwt, tabs

I am facing a problem with the horizontal tab. If we make zoom in the webpage the tabs are going out of view.

Can we make a dropdown list which is in out of view in GWT?

[image]